# magento customer edit not working showing blank page and also customer name not showing

Tags: customer-account

Its error log error which is showing in my root server error log.

Please help me I have use wholesale customer activation extension and removed all file of wholesale customer activation and removed is site live, customer activation & paymentmode from my sql server.

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/vaishf62/public_html/swarnjewelry.com/cron.php on line 41
[23-Apr-2016 09:26:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setRenderer() on a non-object in /home/vaishf62/public_html/swarnjewelry.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 77
[23-Apr-2016 09:27:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackendType() on a non-object in /home/vaishf62/public_html/swarnjewelry.com/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor/Online/Collection.php on line 73
[23-Apr-2016 09:27:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setRenderer() on a non-object in /home/vaishf62/public_html/swarnjewelry.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 77
```

My website Account.php code that showing 77 line error. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solusion of my problem. there was some problem in my mysql. i have cross check "Customer Eav Attribute"  and mgp3_eav_attribute. some file was not available so i just update file and it started to work fine.